# Add customer postcode to specific shipping method on WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I am currently using the following code in the `functions.php` file.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_after_shipping_rate', 20, 2 );
function action_after_shipping_rate ( $method, $index ) {
    // Targeting checkout page only:
    if( is_cart() ) return; // Exit on cart page

    if( 'flat_rate:3' ) {
        echo __("<p>Delivery will take place tomorrow</br> morning between 8-12</p>");
        
    }
    
}
```

---

Now I would like to get the customer postcode, to then add it to my pre-existing code.

Someone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode()` to add the postcode

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate( $method, $index ) {    
    // Targeting checkout page only
    if ( is_cart() ) return;

    // Get shipping postcode
    $shipping_postcode = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
    
    // Compare
    if ( $method->get_id() === 'flat_rate:3' ) {
        // Output
        echo '<p>' . __( 'My text + zipcode = ', 'woocommerce') . $shipping_postcode . '</p>';      
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );
```